# How to render the same field twice but with different name/id attribute?

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I have overriden `user-register.tpl.php` and in it I would like to render same checkbox twice (so that I can submit if either of them have been checked and they are the same I just need to display them twice).

**Example:**

```
<div class='field1'>
   print render($form['field_add_option']);
</div>
<div class='field2'>
   print render($form['field_add_option']);
</div>
```

But this gives same field with same id with same name which is to be expected. Is there a way to change name and id of field before rendering?

I have tried to change the name like (before the second one)
`$form['field_add_option']['und']['#name'] = 'test1';`

But the label `for` and `name` of checkbox are still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The select element don't have `#name` atribute ([Form API Reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#name)). You can implement the `hook_form_alter()` in a custom module.

```
/**
  * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'YOUR_FORM_ID') {
    //here you can make the copy
    $form['field_add_option_copy'] = $form['field_add_option'];
  }   
}
```

You can read this: [Creating modules - a tutorial: Drupal 7.x](https://www.drupal.org/node/1074360)

Comment: @MePo a pleasure help you, good luck in your projects ;-)

Comment: @MePo : About ***Just one more question***": are you aware that changing the original question after it was answered is not compliant to the rules of this site? You should really post that as a new question ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens You are right, sorry. Deleted the comment

Comment: @MePo ok, and why not create a new question for it?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Its because at the end i figured it out. And forgot that i posted here as comment, again my bad will pay more attention to that. But thank you for noticing this

Comment: @MePo no problem, but thanks for clarifying anyway ... Next question?!?!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use hook_form_alter to add your additional fields to the user register form so it's a proper field. Or alternatively add the field to the user object within /admin/config/people/accounts/fields and tick the box to tell it to appear on the registration form.

Comment: But i was wondering how could one "clone" a field but thanks for the explanation